# Create list with all corporate devices and users from intune using Graph rest api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

Our HR department wants to have an "app" = "web page" where they can view if an employee has a corporate notebook. So in case an employee leaves our company they can easily see if the person has a corporate device. The management does not want to give other persons than the IT department access to Endpoint manager.

Because i am new to this, i didn't tried much, but i home someone can 'teach' me how to get this done.I read about this, and i should use the "Graph REST API". Maybe someone can teach me how to get things done.